# Forcing divs to touch each other vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to have a page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuGuE.jpg).

After trying some **CSS** and **HTML** code like this:
CSS Code:

```
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
#header{
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:350px;
    width:750px;
    display:block;
    }
#menu{
    background-color:#096;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#content{
    background-color:#03F;
    width:750px;
    height:400px;
    }
#footer{
    background-color:#900;
    height:120px;
    width:750px;
    display:block;
    bottom:0px;
    position:relative;
    }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<center>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="menu">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</center>
```

it was the same thing but after making some text into "content" part divs got separate. like this[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROJg6.jpg).

Whats the issue in my **CSS** code?

Comment: you should add the pictures right to your question, not just linking them

Comment: @Ben, you can suggest an edit... Why not use it?

Comment: It looks fine when I fiddle it: http://jsfiddle.net/pwt5g39w/ 
You might try to set the margins of the divs to zero.

Comment: I tested it on JSFiddle as well, your code works fine. I am using Chrome by the way.

Comment: @Shaho what's the code for that text that you added?

Comment: I'm not allowed to put picture because I have less than 10 reputations

Comment: Some like this:
<p>dsaas</p>
          <p>sdfsd</p>
          <p>fsdf</p>
          <p>sdf</p>
          <p>sdf</p>
          <p>sdf</p>
          <p>sdfs</p>
          <p>dfsd</p>
          <p>fs</p>
          <p>dfs</p>
          <p>dfs</p>
          <p>df</p>


or every HTML tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Because `p` tag have some default `margin`.

Add CSS like this

```
p{
margin:0px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwt5g39w/1/)

Comment: Thanks it was good. But I thought that the first block of my CSS code forces every tag in body to have a 0 margin. Thanks again

Comment: Ok great. It will not force every tag to margin 0. It will apply only to that particular tag in your case it was body and html tag.